# VB.net automatic property - readonly?

Tags: vb.net, properties

is it possible (and how) to make a readonly automatic property in VB 2010?

```
Public Class Foo  
  Public Property Value As Integer  
  Public Sub New()  
      _Value = 123
  End Sub  
End Class
```

problem is that users can write to the property.
thanx

Comment: I'm not getting what your question is. At a guess I think you want to only allow access to reading the value not writing to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, VB.Net does not support readonly auto properties. See this [MS Connect](http://web.archive.org/web/20110407025020/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/457176/readonly-auto-implemented-properties) issue for the reasoning behind this (specifically the comment made by Jonathan Aneja).

Answer (score 12):

It is now supported in VB14 (Visual Studio 2015 and later):

```
Public Class Foo  
    Public ReadOnly Property Value As Integer = 123
End Class
```

See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-VB-14#read-only-auto-properties

In earlier versions, you need to create a backing field.

Answer (score 2):

No, [it isn't possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx). You will have to create an explicit backing field.

Answer (score 0):

thinkthing,

you may create a code snippet to add a generic property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(v=vs.90).aspx

Be mindful that visual studio has changed the basic way we build properties, with the get set, and now only one line is required with the get set understood. The full getter and setter can be built if you do need logic built within. I refer you here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

and here, to a SO discussion regarding a similar discussion:
[Using snippets to make Class properties in VB.net. prop only gives "property () as " Whats up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011720/using-snippets-to-make-class-properties-in-vb-net-prop-only-gives-property)