# Using snippets to make Class properties in VB.net. prop only gives "property () as " Whats up?

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

As the title says when I type prop I only get a very short version  "property () as "  and no get or set. It used to work in vb.net yet the snippet seems to have totally gone to be replaced by this short one. using VS Ultimate 2012.

It used to work on VS 2010, but on VS2012 and Win 8 the two machines I have no longer have the prop snippet that I had before.  My setup is totally stock except for resharper. Does anyone know if its resharper or something new in vb.net?

This seems to be something new to VB.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

I still have the old snippet I can see it by going Click Insert Snippet on the context menu of the code window, then Code Patterns, then Properties, Procedures, Events, then Define a property. (From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) it just doesn't show on the prop any more

Comment: It's not clear, what have you typed and what has VS auto-completed? Does it compile or not?

Comment: I type prop and expect to get back the full property with get and Set, like this http://i.imgur.com/40tv9ST.png but what I get back now is just "property () as " that you fill with "name() as String". I imagine you can add get set into the braces like C# but can't find any documentation on it. To add get and set I have to type it on the line below but that doesn't generate the private variable. Its a pain in the neck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resharper: Code snippets with tab+tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019256/resharper-code-snippets-with-tabtab)

Comment: Thanks for the link however my resharper doesn't have a prop in Live Templates, in the Templates Explorer. I think its Visual studio http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you type `get` on the next line and press enter you will get the get and set parts. I assume it is because of auto-properties.

EDIT: type `prop` then press TAB twice quickly to get the full expansion.

Comment: Thanks I found that but I just want to generate the usual property with the private variable, this way you have to add them by hand. I guess its just a first world programmers complaint. But this just makes it harder. Is this 'meant' to be like that, or can I change it back?

Comment: Nope... still get only " Property    () As" no matter how fast I tab :-) Apparently its new http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

Comment: @netchicken Oh. Can you temporarily disable Resharper? It works in plain "VS Express for Desktop" on W7x64 for me.

Comment: Nope .. resharper seems innocent, in the link I just posted in the above comment it seems to be a 'feature' of visual studio. maybe it came through in the last update? VS seems intent on turning the property into a glorified variable declaration "Property FirstName As String = "James"  ".

Comment: @netchicken `prop` `TAB` `TAB` type in name for backing variable, e.g. `_z`, `TAB` type in type of property, `TAB` type in name of property, e.g. `Z`. Job done.

Comment: Not in mine it doesn't :-) prop tab (single tab) gives "Property () As" with the cursor before the (). Double tab just pushes the () along one tab.  Then you manually have to add in name and click on the end to add the type. Sure you can then go to the next line and type get and hit Enter, but its still not as good.